# word vba: paragraph symbols showing in listbox

Tags: vba, listbox, symbols, ms-word

this is my first post. I don't know why I get para. format symbols showing in my listbox.

I added text to a word table, sorted it and transferred to listbox. I tried with different selection.clearformatting methods on the table but didn't work. I need to take text from the listbox without the para. symbols and use to search a text. Snippit below

[image]

```
Do Until n = nmax

With Documents("lb2doc")

    .Tables(1).Cell(i, 1).Range.Text = words(n)
    .Tables(1).Cell(i, 2).Range.Text = disctime(n)

    n = n + 1
    i = i + 1

End With

Loop

Dim imax As Long
imax = i

i = 1
'sort table
Documents("lb2doc").Tables(1).Columns(1).Select
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend

Selection.Sort ExcludeHeader:=False, FieldNumber:="Column 2", _
    SortFieldType:=wdSortFieldNumeric, SortOrder:=wdSortOrderDescending, _
    FieldNumber2:="", SortFieldType2:=wdSortFieldAlphanumeric, SortOrder2:= _
    wdSortOrderAscending, FieldNumber3:="", SortFieldType3:= _
    wdSortFieldAlphanumeric, SortOrder3:=wdSortOrderAscending, Separator:= _
    wdSortSeparateByCommas, SortColumn:=False, CaseSensitive:=False, _
    LanguageID:=wdEnglishUS, SubFieldNumber:="Paragraphs", SubFieldNumber2:= _
    "Paragraphs", SubFieldNumber3:="Paragraphs"

Dim j As Long
j = 0

ListBox2.ColumnCount = 3
ListBox2.ColumnWidths = "0;60;20"

Do Until i = imax

ListBox2.AddItem
ListBox2.List(j, 1) = Documents("lb2doc").Tables(1).Cell(i, 1).Range.Text
ListBox2.List(j, 2) = Documents("lb2doc").Tables(1).Cell(i, 2).Range.Text

i = i + 1
j = j + 1

Loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively to first provided answer (which is not working for me) you could try to get text ranges by setting starting and ending points. Your `Do... Loop` will look then as follows:

```
'...your code here
Do Until i = imax
ListBox2.AddItem
With Documents("lb2doc").Tables(1)

    ListBox2.List(j, 1) = Documents("lb2doc").Range(.Cell(i, 1).Range.Start, _
                                            .Cell(i, 1).Range.End - 1)
    ListBox2.List(j, 2) = Documents("lb2doc").Range(.Cell(i, 2).Range.Start, _
                                            .Cell(i, 2).Range.End - 1)
End With
i = i + 1
j = j + 1

Loop
'...rest of your code here
```

Answer (score 1):

The paragraph mark is a carriage return, CHR(13) which also the vb constant vbCr . Just replace these with a blank with the follwing code for your two inserts

```
ListBox2.List(j, 1) = Replace(Documents("lb2doc").Tables(1).Cell(i, 1).Range.Text, vbCr, "")
```

Note, you'll be able to see the paragraph marks in your table if you go to the tools>options menu and choose to display the paragraph marks in the display section.

Comment: The para. symbol doesn't appear anymore, but had to tweak it a bit: now when I call listbox2.list(i,1), it returns a black circle at end of string. But left(listbox2.list(i,1), len(listbox2.list(i,1)) - 1) gets rid of it. Thanks.

Comment: Could be a Carriage Return and a linefeed character. If either replace both with "" or chop the last 2 characters off the end as you are doing with the last character.